# Making use of principles concerning relative and absolute velocity, can we move an object at a velocity that is greater than light?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, experimental-physics, speed-of-light, velocity

I am new to physics, so please do not get angry if this is a stupid question.

First, let's imagine that we are sometime in the future where we have an *extremely* fast spaceship which is travelling in space at a velocity that is $1$ $m/s$ less than that of light( I think this would be $c-1$?)

Now, two astronauts in this spaceship are playing a game of catch. One throws the ball to the other. This ball travels at a velocity of $10$ $m/s$.

In this scenario, are we not correct in assuming that the ball will travel at a velocity greater than that of light ($c + 9$)?

Now, addressing the fact that we probably can't get to a point where we have a spaceship travelling at such a velocity anytime soon, can't we make one using the same principle?

NASA's solar probe travels at a velocity of $393,044$ $km/h$. If we had a giant solar probe which was travelling at this velocity, and another solar probe inside this solar probe, the second solar probe can reach a velocity of $786088$ $km/h$! If we have multiple spaceships inside spaceships, can't we eventually exceed the speed of light with spaceship nesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be on such a spaceship and fire a rocket from it at c-1, but the speed of the rocket would not exceed c. The point is that speeds don't add up simply, so 0.9c plus 0.9c doesn't equal 1.8c. You must apply the relativistic rule of velocity addition.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just looked up "The relativistic rule of velocity addition".

Comment: My pleasure. I hope it all makes sense.